# How to get all child elements using an xpath selector?

Tags: jquery, xpath, css-selectors

In css or jquery this:

```
#related article
```

will select **all** article elements inside the element with the id "related". When I use this xpath selector:

```
//descendant-or-self::*[@id = 'related']/descendant::article
```

It just picks the 1st article element. It doesn't select the rest that are also in that "related" div. How to select all of them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well with XPath (1.0) doing `id('related')//article` or `//*[@id = 'related']//article` does select a node-set of `article` descendant elements. Even your path `//descendant-or-self::*[@id = 'related']/descendant::article` does not restrict the result to a single element so I suspect the problem is how you look at the XPath result or how you evaluate it. The only way a path itself restricts the result to a single node is by doing e.g. `(//*[@id = 'related']//article)[1]`, with other paths I would check the XPath API whether the method you use (`selectSingleNode` or similar?) is the culprit and use `selectNodes` or similar.

Comment: hmm I thought that would be the case too, must be a selenium thing then because the IDE only affects the 1st article element atm with that selector.